# Why learn C at all?

Tags: linux, command-line, linux-kernel, directory

I have come to learn that it is compulsory to learn C language before trying to learn Linux.
What is the reason behind it?Does the knowledge of C somehow aid me in understanding Linux commands,file directories better?
And yes,if I must learn C how do I know when that I have learnt enough to begin Linux.
Thank you

Comment: It's not compulsory at all, unless you refer to Linux Kernel Hacking... from a user perspective you'd be better of learning Bash scripting than C but even that is not compulsory in any way, if you prefer GUI over terminal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Linux is just an operating system kernel. A core component found at the heart of some operating systems like Android, ChromeOS, Ubuntu or Fedora.

You don't use Linux, you use software built for Linux.

For instance, a command line is something that is interpreted by another piece of software called a shell. Such shells include for instance `bash`, the shell of the GNU operating system (some of those systems above (Ubuntu/Fedora) actually extend the GNU OS while using Linux as a kernel). bash existed before Linux and can be built for Linux and dozens other operating systems.

As a user, you *use* `bash` or a file manager application or a web browser or an Android phone or a smart TV, but you don't use Linux. You could say that you *use* an operating system like Debian, Ubuntu or Fedora, but not really Linux.

Learning *Linux* could refer to learning (as a programmer) the internals or the interfaces of that core component of a Android/Ubuntu/Debian/Fedora operating system that is Linux, and as it is written in C, you'd have to learn C beforehand.

But to use a Linux-based system like a PC running Ubuntu or ChromeOS, an Android phone or a smart TV, you certainly don't need to learn C.

Comment: That explains quite a lot